# Exclude all files from folder for plato metric

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, plato

I'm deploy my webapp at a windows maschine (non POSIX command line) and I'm generating JS metric with Plato.

**My Question is** how can I exclude all files from a given folder that contains subfolders via regular expressions with plato.js. 
I tried this command for excluding all minified JS Libs:

```
$ plato -x "^js[a-zA-Z0-9-.\/]*.?js" -r -d report src/app/
```

All JS files of **src/app/js/**/*.js** are not excluded.

I test my regex with rubular: http://rubular.com/r/zbTsv1nIWY (fix underscore issue is optional)

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Remember to escape (.) because you want to match it literally.

i dunno why have you left out the `_` (underscore) but an optional solution can be something like this :

```
^js\/(.*)\.js$
```

folder name starting with js and file name ending with .js

and as you are saying another solution can be to just include the _

```
^js[a-zA-Z0-9-\.\/_]*.?js
```

demo here : http://rubular.com/r/DPqnxtDB6E

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The regex looks correct and handy. I have the feeling that plato itself has a problem. So, I'm debugging plato.